# EOF - scanf and printf

Tags: c++, c

I'm tring to do a simple exercise here, but i need to understand how EOF works first.

```
void main()
{
    char s1[1000];
    while (scanf("%s", s1)!=EOF)
        ;
    printf("%s",s1);
}
```

The idea is to have multiple lines in input, and display them.

The problem I have is that if I put

```
Hello World
This is stackoverflow
```

When printf is called, it only prints

```
stackoverflow
```

Why isn't it printing everything and how do I make it print?

Regards

Comment: `void main()` is wrong; it's `int main(void)`.

Comment: Why is this? void main() has been working for me... :S

Comment: Check this out to know why.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c?lq=1

Comment: A compiler *may* permit `void main()`, but all C compilers *must* support `int main(void)`. (If you're using a book written by an author who doesn't know that, find a better book.)

Comment: The `scanf` function is for *formatted input*. Reading with `%s` reads the next word, and discards whitespace.  If you want your output to look exactly like your input, the simplest way is to use *unformatted* input functions like `fread`, `fgets`, or `getchar`.

Comment: okey ill check with getchar since i don't know how to use the others. Regards

Comment: @PedroLino: `void main()` may "wprk" in the sense that it doesn't cause an obvious error such as a segfault, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's right; there are platforms on which a program that uses `void main()` will crash on exit, or fail to load at all.  Unless your compiler documentation *explicitly* lists `void main()` as a legal signature, you should not use it.  `int main(void)` and `int main(int, char**)` *will* be supported on any implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon `;`:

```
    while (scanf("%s", s1)!=EOF)
        printf("%s",s1);
```

Note that this will still exhibit odd behavior at end of file depending on how it ends exactly. Furthermore, it splits the input into words, which are separated by spaces or new lines. You may want to simply split into lines.

So you may be better served with for instance:

```
    while (gets(s1)!=NULL)
        puts(s1);
```

This code fragments reads your input line by line until end-of-file.

To read everything (or as much as your buffer can hold), you can use:

```
    char s1[1000] = "";
    fread(s1, sizeof(s1) - 1, 1, stdin);
    puts(s1);
```

However, my preferred method of reading a text file is:

```
    using namespace std;
    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line))
    {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
```

That is because usually I want to process a file line by line, and `getline` with a `string` ensures the line buffer is always big enough.

Comment: I would suggest not to use gets(). The next chunk of code (with fread() and puts() works fine.

Comment: Usually you will want text files to be processed line by line. And actually std::getline() is my preferred method of reading them. I have added an example to my post.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
  char s1[1000][20];

  int i = 0 ;

  while (!feof(stdin))
     fgets(s1[i++], 20, stdin) ;

  int j ;
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    printf("%s\n", s1[j]);
```

Here you can enter at most 1000 lines that are maximum 19 characters long.

Comment: Doesn't work. That prints everything i write. The idea is to store what i write and then print it

Comment: That's what the program does. The line you type is stored in `s1`ans then it is printed. Be more specific.

Comment: Hi Michael, the idea is not to press enter and print. The idea is scan a text with multiple '\n' and then print it all

Comment: okey great it works :) can i ask why aren't the the spaces or the \n printed on printf?

Comment: scanf won't work. He wants to read lines. You should use `fgets(s1[i++], 1000, stdin)`

Comment: @PedroLino: Replace `scanf("%s", s1[i++])` by `fgets(s1[i++], 20, stdin)`.

Comment: @PedroLino actually, remove the `!= EOF` part as well.

Comment: WRONG. `while(!feof)` is wrong usage
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: @MichaelWalz: `while(fgets(...) != 0)`

Comment: `while (!fgets(s1[i++], 20, stdin));`

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a loop that reads words into a buffer until it reaches EOF (and does nothing with those words), followed by a `printf` to print the contents of the buffer.  The `printf` is *after* the loop (not in it), so executes once *after* the loop completes.  At that time, the buffer will contain the last word read, so that is what gets printed.

The `EOF` return test means "nothing more to be read", which isn't necessarily an end of file (might be an error condition of some kind), but in practice that distinction can be ignored.  Looping until your reading function returns `EOF` or `NULL` (depends on function) is good practice.

If you want to print each word as it is read, you need to put a `printf` *in* the loop.

If you want to store the words for later processing, you need to store them somewhere.  That means declaring some storage space, or allocating space on the heap, and some bookkeeping to track how much space you've used/allocated.

If you want *lines* rather than words, you should use `fgets` instead of `scanf("%s"`.  Note that `fgets` returns `NULL` rather than `EOF` when there's nothing more to be read.

Comment: So there isn't any way to store all my input and store it to treat it later? I want to store the info from input so i can do something with it...

Comment: But wasn't i storing it in the s1 array?

Comment: @PedroLino: the `s1` array is a simple char array, so each word read overwrites the previous word.  If you want to store multiple words (or multiples lines if you'd rather lines than words), you'll need multiple char arrays

Comment: so a 2D array like s1[1000][20], and when '\n' is pressed, it goes to 2º line. Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Because it only prints the last thing that is read from the file ("stackoverflow"). This is caused by the semicolon after the end of your `while(...);` - this means that you are doing `while(...) { /* do nothing */}` - which is probably not what you wanted

Also, `printf("%s",s1)!='\0';` makes no sense at all. For one thing, `printf` returns the number of characters printed - `'\0'` is the value zero written as a character constant. And of course, doing `!= 0` of the result without some sort of use of the comparison is pretty much pointless too.

Comment: thanks, the !='\0' was a mistake of mine, i've edited :) I want to read the input and store it. That's the idea

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets` instead of `scanf` if you want to read one line at at time. `scanf` will stop reading when it finds a whitespace. `fgets` will read till the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()`. Simple and sweet

```
char buf[1000];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
  fputs(buf, stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how end-of-file works in C.  The input channels are called *input streams*; disk files and `stdin` are both input streams.  The "end-of-file" state is a flag that a stream has, and that flag is triggered when you try to read from a stream, but it turns out there are no more characters in the stream, and there never will be any more. (If the stream is still active but just waiting for user input for example, it is not considered to be end-of-file; read operations will block).

Streams can have other error states, so looping until "end-of-file" is set is usually wrong. If the stream does go into an error state then your loop will never exit (aka. "infinite loop").

The end-of-file state can be checked by `feof`. However, some input operations also can signal an error as well as, or instead of, returning the actual data they were intended to read.  These functions can return the value `EOF`. Usually these functions return `EOF` in *both* cases: end-of-file, and stream error.  This is different to `feof` which only returns `true` in the case of end-of-file.

For example, `getchar()` and `scanf` will return `EOF` if it was end-of-file, but also if the stream is in an error state.

So it is OK to use `getchar()`'s result as a loop condition, but not `feof` on its own.

Also, it is sometimes not OK to use `scanf() != EOF` as a loop condition. It's possible that there is no stream error, but just that the data you requested wasn't there. For example, if you scan for `"%d"` but there are letters in the stream.  Instead, it's better to check for successful conversion (scanf returns the number of successful conversions it performed).   Then when you exit your loop, you can go on to call `feof` and `ferror` to see whether it was due to end-of-file, or error, or just unexpected input.

Comment: -1 for mentioning `feof` -- its not relevant here and will just encourage bad practice

Comment: OP said he wanted to understand how EOF works, and I thought including  an explanation of how the `feof` function actually works would help to avoid bad practice . If I did not mention it, he may assume (as many people do, judging by how many wrong uses of `feof` get posted as questions here) that it was equivalent to scanf returning `EOF`, etc.

Comment: For example there's another answer up there where the guy goes "What you have is a loop that reads words into a buffer until it reaches EOF" , this is confusing at best because if you only check for end-of-file but the stream goes into an error state, then the loop will never exit.

Comment: No, he checks for returning `EOF`, which means "can't read anymore", and which could be either end of file or an error, but the distinction  isn't really important.  The fact that others are incorrectly suggesting `feof` is besides the point.

Comment: "returning `EOF`" and "reaching EOF" are different things, the first one means end-of-file or error, and the second one just means end-of-file. My answer tries to make this distinction clear so that people don't make errors such as using `feof` when they shouldn't.

Comment: I think it adds more confusion than it clarifies.  99% of the time you want "end-of-file or error" and not "end-of-file" in your test, and on those occasions when the distinction between "end-of-file" and "error" is important, you FIRST want the "end-of-file or error" check anyways.